# Index out of bounds error adding two matrices

Tags: java

Error message:

> //Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3
> at mod_2/TestPK.sumofmatrices.main(sumofmatrices.java:12)

My code:

```
package TestPK;

public class sumofmatrices {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[][]= {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
        int b[][]= {{4,3,2},{8,9,4},{1,7,6}};
        int sum[][]= new int[3][3];
        int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
            for(j=0;j<a[0].length;i++) {
                sum[i][j]=a[i][j]+b[i][j];
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
            for(j=0;j<a[0].length;j++) {
                System.out.println(sum[i][j]+"\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You have a typo there `for(j=0;j<a[0].length;i++)`. it should be `j++`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was 2 bug in the code.

1. `for(j=0;j<a[0].length;i++)` -> instead of a.length it was a[o].length
2. In inner loop that is for j, you are incrementing i

The final code is below:

```
public class sumofmatrices {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[][]= {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
        int b[][]= {{4,3,2},{8,9,4},{1,7,6}};
        int sum[][]= new int[3][3];
        int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
            for(j=0;j<a.length;j++) {
                sum[i][j]=a[i][j]+b[i][j];
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
            for(j=0;j<a.length;j++) {
                System.out.println(sum[i][j]+"\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue

```
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<a[0].length;i++) {
        sum[i][j]=a[i][j]+b[i][j];
    }
}
```

You are using i++ in second loop